# Understanding HTML5 Video Tag and streamed Chunks

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

I am trying to understand the HTML5 video tag and how it plays/buffers chunks of streamed data from a WEBM file.

If I break a WEBM file up into say 10 chunks and feed them all into the video tag, the video plays fine. However if I only feed the last 5 chunks into the video tag it doesn't play. 
I get...

INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11

Are there some bytes at the start of the file that are needed?

Does the video tag need to know the specific location it is at in the video to play it? i.e. the content-range

How can I just play a specific chunk(s) of the video?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out prety much all I needed to know on a google group for Webm.
Heres a link...

https://groups.google.com/a/webmproject.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/webm-discuss/6ySds58ZhEQ